# Send picture with httpurlconnection

Tags: android, parameters, httpurlconnection, deprecated

Hi I am making an app which sends picture to a server. The version with the Apache deprecated functions work, but I don't know why I can't get the updated solution to work. Anybody knows where is the error here?

Newest solution : it does not give errors in the logcat but when I go to the server nothing has been uploaded. At first I thought that the error was in how I passed the arguments, but I have tried several different solutions like using Uri.builder, methods which encoded the params using a HashMap and an stringBuilder, passing the string like this... and NOTHING worked. I need help this is really driving me crazy

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        try {
            byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
            byteArrayOutputStream.close();
        }catch (IOException e){

        }
        HttpURLConnection connection;
       try {
            String urlSt = "http://phoenixcoding.tk/SavePicture.php";
            URL url = new URL(urlSt);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            /*Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("name", name)
                    .appendQueryParameter("image", encodedImage);

            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();*/

            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write("name=example&image=" + encodedImage);

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

           connection.connect();

        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
 }
```

Former solution: it works nicely

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        try {
            byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
            byteArrayOutputStream.close();
        }catch (IOException e){

        }ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", encodedImage));

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://phoenixcoding.tk/SavePicture.php");

        try{
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            client.execute(post);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
```

The SavePhoto.php file:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$image = $_POST["image"];
$decodedImage = base64_decode("$image");
file_put_contents("pictures/" . $name . ".JPG", $decodedImage);
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your answers, I finally made it work. I have no idea why is this, but after adding an InputStream object after opening the connection, the pictures uploaded correctly. All I did was add these lines:

```
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        String strLine;
        while ((strLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            str.append(strLine + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your php code:

```
if( isset($_POST["image"]) && !empty($_POST["image"])){
        $profile_pic = '';
        $data= $_POST['image'];

        $data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $data);
        $data = str_replace(' ', '+', $data);
        $binary=base64_decode($data);
        header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
        // Images will be saved under 'www/pictures' folder
        $new_name = $_POST['name'] . '.png';
        $success =file_put_contents('pictures/'.$new_name,$binary);

        $profile_pic = $new_name;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

i guess this line is buggy :- `$decodedImage = base64_decode("$image");` u must write like this instead `$decodedImage = base64_decode($image);`

to debug do this :-

```
<?php 
file_put_contents("post.txt",print_r($_POST,true));
$name = $_POST["name"]; 
.....
?>
```

view that as :- http://phoenixcoding.tk/post.txt

( if the file is not saved then there is permission issue in that case make a directory "test" and give it permission 755 even if it does not work make that directory as 777 and then you url will be http://phoenixcoding.tk/test/post.txt )

What you will do is collect all incoming `$_POST` in file then you will know what post data is coming this will clarify where the error is , on android side or php side if post is okay then android code is okay and issue is in php code.

i hope it will help you fixing the issue...

thanks